# INNER JOIN one column on more than one column in another able?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I have three tables like the following:

ids:

```
id | id_code
1  | abcde
2  | jklmn
3  | pqrst
```

players:

```
full_name| initials
john s.  | js
anne p.  | ap
jen l.   | jl
```

games:

```
id     | player | points | player2 | points2
1      | js     | 2      | ap      | 1 
2      | ap     | 1      | jl      | 3 
2      | jl     | 3      | js      | 4 
3      | jl     | 4      | ap      | 1
```

======

I want to get the following output:

```
id | id_code | full_name | points | full_name_player_2 | points2
```

I can't figure out how to do this with more than one join statement...

Comment: What is the common column on which you need the join between players and games table ? And what is the relation between id_code and players?

Comment: The problem is I'm joining the player in games with the initials column in players.  However, there are two players per game, so I am not sure how to access each player's full name in the final output of the table… @Crusaderpyro

Comment: I am not sure but maybe something like this might help ----------------------

                     
select i.id,i.id_code, p1.full_name, g1.points, p2.full_name, g2.points from
games g1 , games g2, players p1, players p2, ids i where i.id= p1.id and i.id=p2.id and 
p1.initials=g1.player and p2.initials=g2.player2

Comment: ... why does `games` have 2 `player` columns?  What happens if there's a mismatch of points if a player is entered twice?  (You have a player entered twice here, but the points match)  For what reason did you not normalize your data?  (I'd have used `id`, `player_id`, `points` - probably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

With the new structure:

```
select i.id, i.id_code, p1.full_name, g.points, p2.full_name, g.points2
from 
    @ids as i
    inner join @games as g on g.id = i.id
    inner join @players as p1 on g.player = p1.initials
    inner join @players as p2 on g.player2 = p2.initials
```

**OLD DATABASE**

I think this will get your result. Let me know if it works.

```
select i.id, i.id_code, p1.full_name, g.points, p2.full_name, g.points2
from 
    @ids as i
    inner join @players as p1 on p1.id = i.id
    inner join @games as g on g.player = p1.initials
    inner join @players as p2 on g.player2 = p2.initials
```

Test case

```
declare @ids table (
    id int,
    id_code nvarchar(200)
)

declare @players table (
    id int,
    full_name nvarchar(200),
    initials nvarchar(200)
)

declare @games table (
    player nvarchar(200),
    points int,
    player2 nvarchar(200),
    points2 int
)

insert into @ids (id, id_code) values (1, 'abcde')
insert into @ids (id, id_code) values (2, 'jklmn')
insert into @ids (id, id_code) values (3, 'pqrst')


insert into @players (id, full_name, initials) values (1, 'john s.', 'js')
insert into @players (id, full_name, initials) values (2, 'anne p.', 'ap')
insert into @players (id, full_name, initials) values (3, 'jen l.', 'jl')


insert into @games (player, points, player2, points2) values ('js', 2, 'ap', 1)
insert into @games (player, points, player2, points2) values ('ap', 1, 'jl', 3)
insert into @games (player, points, player2, points2) values ('jl', 3, 'js', 4)
insert into @games (player, points, player2, points2) values ('jl', 4, 'ap', 1)
```

Comment: I made a mistake! Players does not have the id field, but the games table does.  This changes your approach I think… @Mathias

Comment: Ok, I updated my query. You could add an expected result to your question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of joining tables where join of internal table will be joined to games.

```
select p1.*, i1.*, g.*, p2.*, i2.* from 
games g inner join (player p1 inner join id i1 on p1.id = i1.id) 
    on g.player = p1.initials
inner join (player p2 inner join id i2 on p2.id = i2.id) 
    on g.player2 = p2.initials
```